# Add subview later to animate alongside superview

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, uiviewanimation

I have a container view - let's call it *socket view* - that has a single subview, it's content view - let's call it *plug view*. This plug view can be nil, i.e. the socket view is currently empty. If it does contain a plug view, it is takes up the entire socket's space, i.e. its frame is the socket's bounds. From an outward perspective you should not even be able to tell that there are in fact two views, since the plug view is always exactly where the socket is.

I am struggling to get animations to work properly: if the plug view exists and is laid out prior to the animation, everything works as expected. However if I set the socket's plug view only when the animation is already running, I get an undesired effect:

The plug view is laid out to where it would be at the end of the animation and does not animate alongside its socket. I would like it to look like it has been there all the time but only became visible just now, i.e. the plug view (and its subviews) should animate alongside the socket, even if I add it while the animation is in progress.

How can I achieve this behavior?

My ideas: obviously the plug view has to be laid out twice: once for its final position, and once more for either where the socket view began animating, or where it has been added. I could compute this frame, apply it without animation and animate to the final frame within a new animation block. In order for the animation timing to be consistent, I would need to have the same curve and duration, but start the animation in the past or somehow forward it. Is this possible? Are there other approaches to having the plug view be full width and height *at all times*?

---

As a follow-up to Rob's answer, here are some more details of what exactly I am looking for:

- The socket view is animating because it's owner's bound size changed. You can think of it as a full-width cell in a table view.
- The plug view may contain subviews of its own along the likes of image views, labels and so on. These should as well join into the animation of the socket view, just as if they have always been there ever since the animation started.
- While theoretically it is possible for a new animation to start while one is running already, I don't really mind the behavior in this edge case.
- It is not necessary for the user to be able to interact with the plug view while the animation is running; this is most likely to happen during an interface orientation change anyway.
- The plug view may decide to change its contents due to an asynchronous model update while animating, but again this is an edge case and I don't mind if the animation doesn't look perfect in this case. Its size, however, does not change - it is always the same as the plug view's size.

Comment: can you post your animation code in here...

Comment: @KusalShrestha I am simply setting the socket view's frame with a different size inside an animation block, there's nothing special going on.

Comment: The animation for an interface orientation change has a duration of 0.3 seconds. Why do you care so much about plugging a view in the middle of that animation?

Comment: I'm not trying to be a dick with that question, btw. Even Apple doesn't try to animate every UI element during a rotation. Try bringing up the keyboard for the location/search box in Safari, then rotating. It hides a bunch of stuff, rotates, and then redisplays the hidden stuff.

Comment: @robmayoff I'm a perfectionist. It's not too big of a deal, that's true, but I would still like like it to look great. I think it looks odd if cells appearing during a rotation are larger or smaller than the existing ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[You can find my test project here.](https://github.com/mayoff/plug-socket-view-animation)

You say your plug view should fully, exactly cover the socket view. We need to worry about two things: the plug's layer position (`layer.position`) and layer size (`layer.bounds.size`).

By default, `position` controls the center of the layer (and view) because the default `anchorPoint` is (0.5, 0.5). If we set `anchorPoint` to (0, 0), then `position` controls the upper-left corner of the layer, and we always want that to be at (0, 0) in the socket's coordinate system. So by setting both `anchorPoint` and `position` to `CGPointZero`, we can avoid worrying about animating `layer.position`.

That just leaves us to animate `layer.bounds.size`.

When you animate a view using UIKit animations, it creates instances of `CABasicAnimation` under the hood. `CABasicAnimation` is a subclass of `CAAnimation` that adds (among other things) `fromValue` and `toValue` properties, specifying start and end values of the animation.

`CAAnimation` conforms to the `CAMediaTiming` protocol, which means it has a `beginTime` property. When you create a `CAAnimation`, it has a default `beginTime` of zero. Core Animation changes that to the current time (see [`CACurrentMediaTime`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/CACurrentMediaTime)) when it commits the current transaction.

But if the animation already has a non-zero `beginTime`, Core Animation uses it as-is. If that `beginTime` is in the past, then the animation is already partially (or even fully) completed when it first appears on-screen, and is drawn with the appropriate amount of progress already made. We can essentially “backdate” an animation.

So if we dig up the `CABasicAnimation` controlling the socket's `bounds.size`, and add it to the plug, the plug should animate in exactly the way we want. When we attach the animation to the plug, its `beginTime` is the time it started animating the socket. So even though we're attaching it to the plug later, it will be perfectly synchronized with the socket. And since we want the plug and the socket to have the same size, the `fromValue` and `toValue` are also already correct.

In my test app, I made the socket pink and the plug blue. Each is a `UIImageView` displaying an image with lines at the edges, so we can be sure that the views have the correct sizes at all times. Here's what it looks like in action:

[image: simple demo]

There is a further twist. If you animate a view that's already animating, UIKit doesn't halt the earlier animation. It adds the second animation, and both animations run concurrently.

This works because UIKit uses *additive* animations. When you animate a view's width from 320 to 160, UIKit sets the width to 160 immediately, and adds an additive animation that goes from 160 to 0. At the start of the animation, the apparent width is 160+160=320, and at the end, the apparent width is 160+0=160.

When UIKit adds a second animation while the first is running, the values of both animations are added to the apparent value used to draw view on the screen. Here's the effect:

[image: multiple animations]

What this means for us is we have to look for all of the socket animations with a `keyPath` of `position.size`, and copy all of them to the plug. Here's the code in my test app:

```
- (IBAction)plugWasTapped:(id)sender {
    if (self.plugView.superview) {
        [self.plugView removeFromSuperview];
        return;
    }

    self.plugView.frame = self.socketView.bounds;
    [self.socketView addSubview:self.plugView];

    for (NSString *key in self.socketView.layer.animationKeys) {
        CAAnimation *rawAnimation = [self.socketView.layer animationForKey:key];
        if (![rawAnimation isKindOfClass:[CABasicAnimation class]]) {
            continue;
        }

        CABasicAnimation *animation = (CABasicAnimation *)rawAnimation;
        if ([animation.keyPath isEqualToString:@"bounds.size"]) {
            [self.plugView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:key];
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the result with multiple simultaneous animations:

[image: demo with multiple animations]

#### UPDATE

Getting the full view hierarchy of the plug view to animate as if it had been there in the first place is frankly too much work.

Here's one alternative:

1. Lay out the plug view at the original size of the socket and create an image of it (the "begin image").
2. Lay out the plug view at the final size of the socket and create an image of it (the "end image").
3. Put a placeholder image view into the socket.
4. Copy the size animation from the socket to the placeholder.
5. Use the size animation to create a contents animation on the placeholder that crossfades its contents from the begin image to the end image.
6. When the animation ends, replace the placeholder with the plug view.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: crossfade demo]

In addition to the imperfection of the crossfade, this version doesn't handle multiple animations running simultaneously. You can find this under the **crossfade** tag in my repository (linked at the top).

Another approach is to just render the plug view at its final size and put that in the placeholder without a crossfade. It looks like this:

[image: stretch end image demo]

I think it looks better this way, and this version handles stacked animations. You can find this under the **stretch-end-image** tag in my repository.

Finally, there's an entirely different approach that I didn't implement. This will only apply to resizing animations that you create yourself—it won't work for the rotation animation created by the system on an orientation change. You can simply animate the bounds of your socket view yourself, with a timer, instead of using UIKit animation. [WWDC 2012 Session 228: Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012-228/) discusses this toward the end. He suggests using an `NSTimer` but I think you'd be better off using a `CADisplayLink`. If you take this approach, the plug view's subviews will all animate perfectly. It's a fair bit more work than using UIKit animations, but should be straightforward to implement.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and making such a great demo project! The animation behavior is exactly how I had it in mind for the plug view itself, but not for subviews of it. I apologize if this was not apparent, but I would like to give the plug view a chance to layout its subviews and animate those as well. Currently any subviews are laid out without animation when inserting the plug view into the hierarchy while an animation is already running. Please see the [pull request](https://github.com/mayoff/plug-socket-view-animation/pull/1) I submitted. Any idea on how to get this to work?

Comment: Edit your question to include more details about the view hierarchy. Why is the socket view animating? Can a new animation start while an existing animation is running? Can the user interact with the plug view, or can its contents change, during the animation?

Comment: I answered your questions and added a little more info. Thanks for your time.

Comment: this is a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

I modified Rob mayoff code this way. Does this help you?

The important changes are in actually using CADisplayLink to update the frame of the plugView and I added an subview with constraints to the plugView. Also changed how the plugView is added and its frame updated.

Just check if this works on you. You should be able to replace this code on the project with no issues.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface UIView (recursiveDescription)
- (NSString *)recursiveDescription;
@end

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *socketWidthConstraint;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *socketHeightConstraint;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *socketView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *plugView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *extraView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    extraView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    extraView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.plugView addSubview:extraView];
    NSLayoutConstraint *c1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:extraView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.plugView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *c2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:extraView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.plugView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *c3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:extraView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.plugView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.5 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *c4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:extraView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.plugView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.5 constant:0];
    [self.plugView addConstraints:@[c1, c2, c3, c4]];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CADisplayLink *link = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayLinkDidFire:)];
    [link addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void)displayLinkDidFire:(CADisplayLink *)link {
    CGSize size = [self.socketView.layer.presentationLayer frame].size;
    self.plugView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [self.plugView layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (IBAction)plugWasTapped:(id)sender {
    if (self.plugView.superview) {
        [self.plugView removeFromSuperview];
        return;
    }

    CGSize size = [self.socketView.layer.presentationLayer frame].size;
    self.plugView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [self.socketView addSubview:self.plugView];
}
- (IBAction)bigButtonWasTapped:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:10 animations:^{
        self.socketWidthConstraint.constant = 320;
        self.socketHeightConstraint.constant = 320;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

- (IBAction)smallButtonWasTapped:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
        self.socketWidthConstraint.constant = 160;
        self.socketHeightConstraint.constant = 160;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the plug view always exist as a child view of the socket view, but set `hidden = YES`? Or you could use `alpha = 0`. Then when you want to show it, simply set it to hidden = `hidden = NO` or `alpha = 1`.

That way your plug view will always "come along for the ride" when you're animating the socket view.

BTW, your terminology is disorienting to those of us who work with TCP sockets. ("Sockets? What?")

Comment: This is not possible, I am trying to reuse the plug views like UITableView does, only the socket views should be kept alive at all times.